# Vakil's FOAG Exercise 11.3.C

Tags: algebraic-geometry, problem-solving

I have been thinking about the exercise 11.3.C of Vakil's FOAG. The answers posted here [Trouble with Vakil's FOAG exercise 11.3.C](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1105333/trouble-with-vakils-foag-exercise-11-3-c) are not clarifying enough for me, since I have though of the following example: Take $\mathbb{P^2_{\mathbb{R}}}$ with coordinates $(x:y:z)$ and (with the notation of the exercise) set

$H = V(z),\quad X = V((x^2+y^2-z^2))$

Then, these 2 clearly don't meet in $\mathbb{P^2_{\mathbb{R}}}$ (although they meet in $\mathbb{P^2_{\mathbb{C}}}$).

What am I missing here? Does anyone have a proof for this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: In algebraic geometry, 'points' do not necessarily have co-ordinates from the base field, if the base field is not algebraically closed. For example, $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{R}}$ has `strange points' like the one defined by $x^2+1=0$, where $x$ is the co-ordinate function. Notice that this is not quite a point defined over complex numbers, since $\pm\sqrt{-1}$ are identified.

Comment: Thus, in this case we'd say that these 2 meet at $(x^2+y^2,z)$, which is an homogeneous prime ideal not containing $(x,y,z)$ (thus a point in Proj($\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]$)), isn't it?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Nice! Thank you for your enlightening comment Mohan